# Extraction of each HSV value from an image using OpenCV and C++

Tags: c++, opencv, hsv

I used the code below to extract each HSV value from any image and to print each value on the screen.

```
Mat image_HSV;
cvtColor(ori_image, image_HSV, CV_BGR2HSV);

Mat mask;
inRange(image_HSV, Scalar(100, 0, 0), Scalar(100, 255, 255), mask);

image_HSV.setTo(Scalar(0, 0, 0), mask);

int h = 0;
int s = 0;
int v = 0;

int col = image_HSV.cols; 
int row = image_HSV.rows;

int corow = col * row;  // image's full pixel number

for (int i = 0; i < image_HSV.cols; i++) {      // image row pixel
    for (int j = 0; j < image_HSV.rows; j++) {  // image col pixel
        Vec3b hsv = image_HSV.at<Vec3b>(i,j);

        h += hsv.val[0];
        s += hsv.val[1];
        v += hsv.val[2];

        if (hsv[0] != 100) {
            hsv[0] = 0;
            hsv[1] = 0;
            hsv[2] = 0;
        }
    }
}

cout << "H: " << h / corow << "% \n";
cout << "S: " << s / corow << "% \n";
cout << "V: " << v / corow << "% \n";

waitKey(0);
return 0;
```

I used all red color image for this time, which RGB values were 255, 0, 0.

However, I have some strange results from this code.

As I know, each H,S,V value range is covered by 0-360, 0-100, and 0-100, respectively.

Further, I also followed the post linked below but I still have a trouble to get right values.

[OpenCV (C++) - Set HSV values of a pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846581/opencv-c-set-hsv-values-of-a-pixel)

But, I still don't know how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have a read here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/54071998/2836621

Comment: May I suggest that you provide a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . In this case it's missing which files to include and an incomplete function definition.

Comment: Thank you Mark, I appreicate your answer. But I have already checked that link and I know how to convert RGB image to HSV image as well. However, my problem is that I want to read and print each H,S,V value from the converted image on the screen. Not for specific pixel's value, but all the pixel's average value.

Comment: so you want to do is the [mean](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mean) of the image in HSV? For that, convert it as @MarkSetchell says and use the mean function. It gives a cv::Scalar that it has the average for each channel

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I still got over 100 values for saturation and brightness value when I applied the red color image (255,0,0).

Comment: So, is there any problem on the code above to convert RGB values to HSV values from the image? Sorry for my ignorance.. but I was stuck on this problem for a week... and no way to solve this problem... please help me.. :(

Comment: What are you using `inRange()` for? Why are you iterating over all the pixels - firstly OpenCV will calculate statistics automatically for you and secondly, if you only count pixels that are pure red you might as well just look up the HSV value of a single red pixel because they will certainly average to that if that's all you count? Finally, you say you want to calculate each pixel's value, but you say you want the mean of all of them - which is it please?

Comment: You also say you have read the link I provided and yet still appear to think Hues range between 0-360 whereas the point of the link was that Hues vary between 0-180 for unsigned char images.

Comment: Okay, thank you Mark, I got it. I fixed it and it works great!! I really appreciate your comment!